# Run-time 429 error in VB6 calling .net assembly in Windows Server 2008

Tags: com, vb6, com-interop

I tried the simple app from the link [How to call a Visual Basic .NET or Visual Basic 2005 assembly from Visual Basic 6.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817248)

.net code

```
    <ComClass(ComClass1.ClassId, ComClass1.InterfaceId, ComClass1.EventsId)> _
    Public Class ComClass1

    #Region "COM GUIDs"
        ' These  GUIDs provide the COM identity for this class 
        ' and its COM interfaces. If you change them, existing 
        ' clients will no longer be able to access the class.
        Public Const ClassId As String = "6DB79AF2-F661-44AC-8458-62B06BFDD9E4"
        Public Const InterfaceId As String = "EDED909C-9271-4670-BA32-109AE917B1D7"
        Public Const EventsId As String = "17C731B8-CE61-4B5F-B114-10F3E46153AC"
    #End Region

        ' A creatable COM class must have a Public Sub New() 
        ' without parameters. Otherwise, the class will not be 
        ' registered in the COM registry and cannot be created 
        ' through CreateObject.
        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New()
        End Sub

Public Function myFunction() As Integer
      Return 100
   End Function

    End Class
```

vb6 code

```
Dim myObject As TestProj.COMClass1
Set myObject = New TestProj.COMClass1
MsgBox myObject.myFunction
```

and it works on my dev machine using .Net 4.0 and VS 2010 and VB6. When I copy the files to a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine and registered the assembly using the format Regasm AssemblyName.dll /tlb: FileName.tlb /codebase and also strongly signed the assembly I get the error 429 cannot create ActiveX component. I checked the registry and I see the classid in there. What am I missing?
Thanks

Also, I have a legacy vb6 app that is using RDS (remote data services) to create object on another server using Com+ but I want to just change it to run the .Net dll on the same server as the vb6 exe. Is there a way to run the exe on the server from another client PC without registering the .Net dll (tlb) or do I need to create a setup.exe to package everything? I tried to run the same exe on my Virtual XPMode and I get the same error even when I create a setup app. It only works on my dev machine.

Comment: Use the correct version of Regasm.exe, the one in the Framework subdirectory, not the Framework64 subdirectory.  And use SysInternal's ProcMon utility if you still have trouble.

Comment: You are correct! Good guess that I was using the wrong framework folder. I just thought of it and tried it before I saw your answer. I was going to write an answer about it. My XP virtual got the same error even though I created a setup package thinking that would register the dll correctly. So I created a reg file with the regasm.exe and imported it to the registry on XP and it worked also. So looks like I would have to import the registry settings on all client PCs. The only other way I can think of doing this withough registering the file is to use DCOM.

Comment: Your last paragraph would be better off as its own question.